# blackberry default text alignment

Tags: blackberry, text, default, text-alignment

In my application, I'm using the default text aliment for text alignment.
Some time when application installed on a different devices, the text aligned to right instead of left.
How do I change the default alignment without adding alignment to each text?

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
if((Display.getWidth()==320) && (Display.getHeight()==240))
{
    //set the alignment
}
else if((Display.getWidth()==360) && (Display.getHeight()==480))
{
    //set alignment
}
```

and so on...